# How to set a rewrite rule in Charles Proxy, when there is a '?' included?

Tags: regex, proxy, url-rewriting, charles-proxy

I am using Chales Proxy, and it helped me a lot so far. For testing, I use the rewrite rule to change the Path parameters. This works pretty well, as long as I do not try to set the rewrite rule on a a Path which includes a question mark:

**Type:** Path

**URL sample:** /get/article/123456/n/20121208/?

**Rewrite rule:** /? -> /showAdmin=true/?

My guess is that the questionmark is a placeholder, which I can not use as a match value. I tried to escape it, but it did not work either.

Has anybody got an idea how I can work around it? A hint how to work with regEx in Charles would also help. The path is always the same.

Best,
Klaas

Answer (score 3):

Just putting this as an answer because it was driving me nuts. In order to use groups you basically enclose things within the regex in a parentheses group like so:

`whatever/(.*)/(.*)\.html`

And then in the replace field, you put you refer to that parentheses group as $1, $2 and so on I believe from left to right.

`/whatever/$1/$2.json`

I believe what stema posted below should work but in case you were trying to use groups, this is how you would do it.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is not a placeholder, its a quantifier. So, `/?` means match zero or one slashes.

A quick search for the [documentation](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) says

> Regex support may be enabled, providing Perl-style regular expressions for your match.

Then this should work

```
/\?$
```

The `$` would match the string end, if the `?` should be matched before the string end also, just remove it.